# Can't get ES6 promise value to display in AngularJS view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-promise

I'm trying to use the Pinterest JavaScript SDK to get some pin data for a project. I have a method in a Pinterest service I created that gets called in my HomeController. I tried throwing the response inside of a promise so I could put it on my HomeController's `$scope` and display it in my view.  However, $scope.pins is undefined in my view.  Why is it `undefined`?  Seems like the promise is working. Still learning promises.

#### Pinterest Service

```
function getBoardPins (id) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    PDK.request('/v1/boards/' + id + '/pins/', 'GET', {fields: 'id,link,url,creator,board,created_at,note,color,counts,media,attribution,image,metadata'}, function (response) {
      if (response) {
        resolve(response);
      }

      reject();
    });
  });
}
```

#### Home Controller

```
Pinterest.getBoardPins('490329546869188172').then(function (response) {
  $scope.pins = response.data;
});
```

#### View

```
<h1>Pinterest</h1>
<div ng-repeat="pin in pins">
  <div>{{pin}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried to log `response` in `PDK.request()` promise? Is your `resolve(response)` going to be called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `$q.when` to convert the ES6 promise to an AngularJS promise:

```
$q.when(Pinterest.getBoardPins('490329546869188172'))
  .then(function (response) {
    $scope.pins = response.data;
});
```

AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. **Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding,** exception handling, property watching, etc.

To bring an ES6 promise into the AngularJS execution context, use `$q.when`.

> ### $q.when
>
> Wraps an object that might be a value or a (3rd party) then-able promise into a `$q` promise. This is useful when you are dealing with an object that might or might not be a promise, or if the promise comes from a source that can't be trusted.
>
> [— AngularJS $q Service API Reference - $q.when](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when)

---

### Alternately create the promise with the [$q constructor.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#-q-constructor)

```
function getBoardPins (id) {
  //return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
    PDK.request('/v1/boards/' + id + '/pins/', 'GET', {fields: 'id,link,url,creator,board,created_at,note,color,counts,media,attribution,image,metadata'}, function (response) {
      if (response) {
        resolve(response);
      }

      reject();
    });
  });
}
```

This creates a promise that is integrated with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle.

Comment: Thank you so much, really good answer!  That fixed the problem and totally makes sense as well.